# Twitter Card fails validation - why is this not picking up any tags

Tags: html, twitter, share

I have a bare bones html page created for testing sharing via twitter. When I test this out in twitter card validator it says:

```
INFO:  Page fetched successfully
WARN:  No metatags found
```

Here is the complete webpage:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" name="Content-Type">
      <meta name="twitter:card"              content="summary_large_image">
      <meta name="twitter:title"             content="Title for this page">
      <meta name="twitter:description"       content="115 character description">
      <meta name="twitter:image"             content="https://urlToAzure/thatends/withjpgfilename.jpg">
      <title>Page Title</title>
   </head>

   <body bgcolor="#CCCCCC">

      <div id="allContentInBody">
         Test page.
      </div>    

   </body>
</html>
```

Here is the public link of this webpage:

https://www.privatebox.com/casa/test.html

I've updated robots.txt to allow is all.

EDIT 2: I made some progress and have additional information.

My setup is a NGINX acting as reverse proxy to node.js for all traffic, no static pages.

I setup a static page that will be served by NGINX itself. And now Twitter card validator works. I see the image and other information in the card.

So the problem is that somehow when NGINX is forwarding the request to node.js - the page served seems to be failing twitter's card validation. In that it is not able to see the metatags.

I'm certain that NGINX is not stripping the meta tags. so there is something else that twitter tries to do which my node server does not get to see and is thus failing.

Any advice on NGINX as reverse proxy with node.js and how to get twitter to work is appreciated.

Comment: Not really possible without a live URL to check, but you could follow Twitter's troubleshooting guide https://twittercommunity.com/t/not-whitelisted-unable-to-render-or-no-image-what-to-do-next/62736

Comment: Thanks @AndyPiper.
I'll work on making the link public soon. In the meanwhile, I'll try the link you've shared. So far, I can tell that robots.txt might be a file Twitterbot cares about so I created it just now. However when I do the card validation again, no change in results and I don't see a fresh twitterbot request for robots.txt on my site. I'll spend more time trying out suggestions from the link you shared and report back.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. It was on the node Server, I was serving the file with

```
 res.write(<contents>)
 res.end().
```

I changed it to

```
res.send(<contents>)
```

and that fixed the issue. The metatags are now seen by twitter card validator and the image gets picked up too.